# Hibernate mapping using xml

Tags: hibernate

It may be a very silly question As I am new to hibernate. 
I am using `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `Event.hbm.xml` but while starting it is giving this error.

> org hibernate Mapping Exception: Unknown entity

`hibernate.cfg.xml` and `Event.hbm.xml` are in the same folder.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<sessionfactory>
 <propertyname="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<propertyname="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
<property name="connection.username">system</property>
 <property name="connection.password">bharat</property>
 <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property><propertyname="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<mapping resource="Event.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```

This is my `Event.hbm.xml` code:

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="bharat.bisht.domain.Event" table="EVENTS">
            <id name="id" column="EVENT_ID">
                <generator class="native"></generator>
            </id>
            <property name="date" type="timestamp" column="EVENT_DATE">        </property>
            <property name="title" column="EVENT_TITLE"></property>
        </class>
```

Event.java

```
package bharat.bisht.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;


public class Event {
private Long id;
private String title;
private Date date;

public Event() {}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

private void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}}
```

[image: stack]

Comment: post the code of your `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `Event.hbm.xml`.

Comment: Added the relevant code.

Comment: This is the code of your `Event.hbm.xml`, please post the rest of your code.

Comment: <mapping resource="Event.hbm.xml"/> twice. Why?

Comment: Sry that was typo error :(

Comment: Where's your `Event` class is it under the package `bharat.bisht.domain` ?

Comment: package bharat.bisht.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @author bharat
 *
 */
public class Event {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Date date;

    public Event() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;}}

Comment: Are you sure that `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `Event.hbm.xml` are in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't matter if your `Event.hbm.xml` is on the same folder or not

try like this -

```
<mapping resource="(full path)/Event.hbm.xml"/>
```

and sometimes your dialect path dont support Oracle10gDialect

try `org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect`

Comment: Already used:
<propertyname="dialect">
 org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

Used this this time but didn't solve the problem: 
<mapping resource="src/main/resources/Event.hbm.xml"/>

Comment: Any answers for this particulay query of mine?

Comment: Let me rank up your question. I hope somebody knows.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the name of your "date" column to a different name? date is a reserved word in Oracle.

Comment: That has been changed in the mapping file as the EVENT_DATE .